# AngularJS - how to handle circular watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I am working with a directive that is given a date in form of a unix timestamp via two-way binding, but also offers a calendar widget to change the selection.

The calendar widget works with a date object, and I am unable to change the input data format and I do not want to rework the calendar to support unix timestamp. Also this is just an example and the question is about general way of working with circular watchers.

The scope would look like this:

```
scope.selectedUnixTimestamp; // this comes from the outside
scope.selectedDate;

scope.$watch('selectedUnixTimestamp', function(newV, oldV) {
    $scope.selectedDate = new Date(newV*1000);
});
scope.$watch('selectedDate', function(newV, oldV) {
    $scope.selectedUnixTimestamp = Math.floor(newV.getTime()/1000 + 0.000001);
});
```

My question is: **what do I do in order to avoid extra calls to $watch callbacks?** Obviously if I choose a new date, the flow will be following:

1. Watcher #2 is called - it modifies selectedUnixTimestamp
2. Watcher #1 is called - it modifies selectedDate
3. Watcher #2 is called again (new object reference) - it modifies selectedUnixTimestamp

But I don't want any of those calls besides the first one. How do can I achieve it?

---

Obviously one way would be to do something like:

```
scope.selectedUnixTimestamp; 
scope.selectedDate;

var surpressWatch1 = false;
var surpressWatch2 = false;

scope.$watch('selectedUnixTimestamp', function(newV, oldV) {
    if(surpressWatch1) { surpressWatch1 = false; return; }
    $scope.selectedDate = new Date(newV*1000);
    surpressWatch2 = true;
});
scope.$watch('selectedDate', function(newV, oldV) {
    if(surpressWatch2) { surpressWatch2 = false; return; }
    $scope.selectedUnixTimestamp = Math.floor(newV.getTime()/1000 + 0.000001);
    surpressWatch1 = true;
});
```

But it quickly becomes a hell to maintain a code like that.

---

Another way would be to do something like:

```
scope.selectedUnixTimestamp; 
scope.selectedDate;

scope.$watch('selectedUnixTimestamp', function(newV, oldV) {
    if(newV*1000 === scope.selectedDate.getTime()) { return; }
    $scope.selectedDate = new Date(newV*1000);
});
scope.$watch('selectedDate', function(newV, oldV) {
    if(scope.selectedUnixTimestamp*1000 === newV.getTime()) { return; }
    $scope.selectedUnixTimestamp = Math.floor(newV.getTime()/1000 + 0.000001);
});
```

But it might be very costful if the data transformation is more complicated than `* 1000`

---

Another way would be to watch on primitive value instead of a date object:

```
scope.$watch('selectedDate.getTime()', function(newV, oldV) {
```

But this only works with this particular example and does not solve the general issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular framework is built on the following assumption: 
The true and trustable value of something, ready to be synchronized with a REST service for example, exists once in the model.

Keeping this in mind, you never write circular watchers. 
And in case you have two different ways to alter a model value, you would write directives requiring ngModelController instance and providing the right formatter and parser functions.

Comment: it's not that simple - I may need to do different things based on the source of the change; e.g if change came from the calendar, I may want to do X, but if the change came from the two way binding I may need to do Y - in this case I still need two variables to watch

Comment: That is the typical concern of pushing formatters and parsers in the specific arrays looped in by the ngModelController implementation and overriding its $render method.

Answer (score 2):

How to work with circular watches? I guess answer is, try not to do it.

You can try this, although I am sure there are better solutions to your example.

**Use only one watch function:**

You can use a function as first parameter to the watch. This function will be called until the value it returns settles (is the same as last time). You can hence create a $watch like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return {
        timestamp: scope.selectedUnixTimestamp, 
        date: scope.selectedDate
    }
}, function(newVal, oldVal) { 
    // Note that newVal and oldVal here is on the form of the object you return in the watch function, and hence have properties: timestamp and date.
    // You can compare newVal.date to oldVal.date (same with timestamp) to see which one has actually changed if you need to do that.
}
true);  // You need a deep watch (the true param) to watch the properties on the object
```

Comment: that's a curious approach; however if I need to perform some heavy calculations this callback could become really big; but I guess I could refactor those to separate functions so this could work

Comment: First comment: No, remember that the function doing the heavy work only fires whenever there actually is a change. And I presume you only put work in there which you actually want to perform. Again, the first function is fired several times, and should be very light (basically just return data for comparision). The other one fires upon change, and can be pretty heavy if necessary. Second comment: Sure, if you consider it more legible, please use that. Note that Angular will parse the string and create a function of it behind the scenes, so there is a hidden function call (of course).

Comment: Updated with some comments about how to figure out what actually changed.

Comment: Ah, but if the date is modified, and this watcher will update the timestamp accordingly, I still have the original problem - it will run for the second time; Sure, I can add another comparison and do certain things only if `newVal.date.getTime() !== newVal.timestamp*1000`, but I can do that too with the original structure of two watchers; I will add that to my question

Comment: That's true, and I see my suggestion doesn't get you much further in that regard, but it has one advantage which is that if both values have changed at once (say a function in the controller updates both on the same time) you can detect that in the watch. Having two watches, you have no control which one is called first. Nevertheless, I don't see how you intend to solve a circular watch, without somehow giving one priority over the other and forcing both values to evalute equal to eachother like in the date example (in which case the watch will settle eventually, but may fire twice)?

Comment: I don't see that too, I wonder if anyone can think of anything, I thought this is a common issue